Trouble making API POST request with Next.js
I am new when it comes to anything related to backend, also new in Next.js and TypeScript.
I am trying to make a POST request to an API, which should receive formData and create a new listing based on that formData. I am trying to do this with Next.js server actions and route handlers.
Here is my code:
This is from the form component:
const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const form = e.currentTarget as HTMLFormElement;
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    
    const address = formData.get("address");
    const mail = formData.get("mail");
    const region_id = selectedRegion?.id; //these come from states
    const agent_id = selectedAgent?.id;  //these come from states
    const city_id = selectedCity?.id;   //these come from states
    const area = formData.get("area");
    const price = formData.get("price");
    const type = formData.get("type");
    const cover = formData.get("cover"); // This is the file input

    try {
        console.log(address, mail, region_id, agent_id, city_id, area, price, type, cover);

        const newFormData = new FormData();

        newFormData.append("address", address as string);
        newFormData.append("mail", mail as string);
        newFormData.append("region_id", region_id as any);
        newFormData.append("agent_id", agent_id as any);
        newFormData.append("city_id", city_id as any);
        newFormData.append("area", area as string);
        newFormData.append("price", price as string);
        newFormData.append("type", type as string);
        newFormData.append("cover", cover as File); 
        
        await addListingAction(newFormData)
    } catch (error) {
        alert(`Error: ${error}`);
    }
};

This is my server action:
export async function addListingAction(formData: FormData) {
  try {
    await addListing(formData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    revalidatePath("/")
  }
}

my api.ts file:
export async function addListing(formData: FormData) {

  return await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/add-listing`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}

and my route.ts file:
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const formData = await req.formData();

    const address = formData.get("address");
    const mail = formData.get("mail");
    const region_id = formData.get("region_id");
    const agent_id = formData.get("agent_id");
    const city_id = formData.get("city_id");
    const area = formData.get("area");
    const price = formData.get("price");
    const type = formData.get("type");
    const cover = formData.get("cover") as File | null;

    const form = new FormData();
    if (address) form.append("address", address);
    if (mail) form.append("mail", mail);
    if (region_id) form.append("region_id", region_id);
    if (agent_id) form.append("agent_id", agent_id);
    if (city_id) form.append("city_id", city_id);
    if (area) form.append("area", area);
    if (price) form.append("price", price);
    if (type) form.append("type", type);
    if (cover instanceof File) form.append("cover", cover);

    const REDBERRY_API_TOKEN = process.env.REDBERRY_API_TOKEN;

    if (!REDBERRY_API_TOKEN) {
      throw new Error("Missing API token");
    }


    const response = await fetch('https://api.real-estate-manager.redberryinternship.ge/api/real-estates', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${REDBERRY_API_TOKEN}`,
      },
      body: form,
    });


if (!response.ok) {
  let errorResponse;
  try {
    errorResponse = await response.json();
  } catch {
    errorResponse = await response.text();
  }
  console.error('HTTP error! Status:', response.status, 'Response:', errorResponse);
  return NextResponse.json(
    { message: 'API request failed', error: errorResponse },
    { status: response.status }
  );
}


  const listing = await response.json();

  return NextResponse.json({ listing }, { status: 201 });

  } catch (error) {
    const message = error instanceof Error ? error.message : 'An unexpected error occurred';
    console.error('Error creating listing:', message);
  return NextResponse.json(
    { message: 'Failed to create listing', error: message },
    { status: 500 }
  );
  }
}

The API documentation says that the curl request looks like this:
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://api.real-estate-manager.redberryinternship.ge/api/real-estates' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer API_TOKEN' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'region_id=1' \
  -F 'price=100000' \
  -F 'zip_code=0101' \
  -F 'area=100.5' \
  -F 'city_id=1' \
  -F 'address=example address' \
  -F 'agent_id=371' \
  -F 'bedrooms=3' \
  -F 'is_rental=0' \
  -F 'image=@review3.png;type=image/png' \
  -F 'description=house near metro station'

and the response looks like this:
"price": "100000",
  "zip_code": "0101",
  "area": "100.5",
  "city_id": "1",
  "address": "example description",
  "agent_id": "371",
  "bedrooms": "3",
  "is_rental": "0",
  "description": "house near metro station",
  "image": "https://api.real-estate-manager.redberryinternship.ge/storage/images/vZ6KRjLiBIoVqwl4GMniE598mAzno8wqzCkZyg3f.png",
  "created_at": "2024-09-15T16:43:21.000000Z",
  "id": 450

The error I am getting is:

Error creating listing: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
POST /api/add-listing 500 in 931ms
{
message: 'Failed to create listing',
error: 'Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON'
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In async function POST you have properly handled fetch response errors. In async function addListing you haven't.

You may want to ask the admin at real-estate-manager.redberryinternship.ge

In your curl request you're setting at least one header that you're not sending with your fetch request. Make sure those align if you expect to get the same results

use req: NextRequest and and make sure that /api/add-listing  folder exists.

Still the same error after using NextRequest, and /api/add-listing does indeed exist.

I would use postman or open your network tabs to see what actual response you're getting from the API.
The invalid json: <!doctyp... error is typically seen when you are expecting a json response (which you are, which heads accept: application/json and .json()) but instead you're given an HTML page instead (like a normal GET request, for example)
This could be because: (1) Your actual route API env var isn't when you expect it to be (so instead of going to the apidomain.com/ is goes to localhost/ (which would not serve JSON) or (2) there's an error with the API
Check the API var

The 500 error masking is also totally fine to do (just let the user know something "went wrong", but be sure to log the actual error codes on the server so you always have the proper errors. It'll make debugging much easier. I'm not sure if the error code is included in the console.error('Error creating listing:', message);

Was able to resolve the problem by adding invisible inputs in my form, which would take values from states for region_id, city_id.... instead of appending this values to the formData.
